# Segmentation fault: 11, in TCP client

Tags: c, linux

Segmentation error usually come when there is some error in memory allocation or management. But in this case I am not sure whats wrong. Any suggestions would help. I am trying to connect to a `select()` server.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netdb.h>

#define INPUT "Socket TCP"
#define BUF_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int sockt;
    struct sockaddr_in serv;
    struct hostent *host;
    char buff[BUF_SIZE];


    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;

    /*host = argv[1];
     host = malloc (1 + strlen (argv[1]));
     */


    host = gethostbyname (argv[1]);
    printf("1");
    if(host == 0)
    {
        perror("gethostbyname failed");
        close(sockt);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("gethost name succeeded \n");

    sockt = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    printf("2");
    if(sockt < 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("socket connected \n");

    printf("3");
    memcpy(&serv.sin_addr, host->h_addr, host->h_length);
    serv.sin_port = htons(1234); /*Convert from host byte order to network byte order*/
    printf("4");

    /*Condition to check if the client has connected*/
    if(connect(sockt, (struct sockaddr *) &serv, sizeof(serv)) <0)
    {
        perror("Failed to connect");
        close(sockt);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("5");

    /*Condition to check if the data is sent*/
    if(send(sockt, INPUT, sizeof(INPUT), 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to send the data");
        close(sockt);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("data sent");
    printf("The data sent is %s\n", INPUT);
    close(sockt);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fair warning, `close(socket);` in the case of a failed `gethostbyname()` closes an indeterminate `int` value. That line of code shouldn't even be there. I'm debating +1'ing this because you've obviously at-least-tried to stepwise-debug it via sprinkled `printf`, which frankly is far initiative than most people take up.

Comment: I couldn't understand, so I removed the close socket statement but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, what are you using for a general guide to Unix socket programming. [**Beej's Guide to Network Programming**](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html), is a little dated, but pretty good compared to most, and working through the examples can be very helpful if you don't have something like it already.

Comment: What are the odds that you're not actually running your program with a valid command line argument? Can you show how you're starting it up?

Comment: Thank you. Beej's is one of my reference resources, but this one is combination of my various materials.

Comment: what command line argument you giving while running this client code

Comment: ./tcp_client but I have tried with a port number too.

Comment: It expects a host name, i.e. `www.somewhere.com` for a first argument. Post the **exact** command line you're running this with in your question as an addendum at the bottom.

Comment: yes thats an issue u must give hostname and not port, becz of which u getting seg fault.

Answer (score 1):

As [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) mentioned, the issue is you are not providing hostname or ip address.
Neither you are checking for the number of arguments provided!

I run your program and didn't find any segfault with proper argument i.e host_name provided.

You should include following check:

```
if(argc<2)
{
   printf("usage : %s hostname",argv[0]);
   exit(0);
}
```

This won't allow program to proceed if no host name is provided.

Run program as `./<excecutable> <host_name>`

try with localhost first.

i.e. `./tcp_client localhost`

hope this helps!